# On homomorphisms of a group $G$ to a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{8}\times \mathbb{Z}_{12}\times \mathbb{Z}_{30}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ denotes  the cyclic  group of order $n$. Does $G$ admit a homomorphism onto $\mathbb{Z}_{45}$? What about $\mathbb{Z}_{120}$?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

(1) $\Bbb Z_{45}$ has an element of order $9$; does $G$?

(2) What is the order of $\langle 1,1,1\rangle$ in $G$?

Comment: @maryam: Does we know that if $\phi:G\to G'$ a homomorphism, then $|\phi(g)|\big||g|$?

Comment: @Babak: That’s not necessarily true unless $\varphi$ is actually an isomorphism. After all, the trivial group is a homomorphic image of **every** group! What we do know is that $|\varphi(g)|$ divides $|g|$.

Answer (score 1):

Another hint: Prove that if $\phi$ is an homomorphism then the order of $\phi(a)$ divides the order of $a$.